# Setting up AWS SES DKIM in Linode

Tags: email, spf, cname-record, linode, txt-record

I am having trouble finding a resource to help with this process, please let me know if there exists documentation somewhere you know of.  I am trying to set up AWS SES, my hosting is at Linode.  I think I have got the MX and SPF record correct, but now for the DKIM I am confused.  Amazon gives me three DKIM entries like

```
Name                               Type   Value
gibberish1._domainkey.example.com  CNAME  gibberish1.dkim.amazonses.com
gibberish2._domainkey.example.com  CNAME  gibberish2.dkim.amazonses.com
gibberish3._domainkey.example.com  CNAME  gibberish2.dkim.amazonses.com
```

but when I go to add a CNAME file to Linode, it looks like

```
Hostname:   ___________________
Aliases to: ___________________
TTL:                      _____
```

So do I just map `Hostname = Name` and `Alias = Value`?  It feels like I might be supposed to set it up as a `TXT` record instead, since I have `Name/Value` pairs, but I think that is different?  Thank you.

Comment: I don't know the Linode-Interface, but I suspect it's `Hostname: example._domainkey.example.com` and `Aliases to: gibberish1.dkim.amazonses.com`

Comment: Yes it looks like just Hostname -> Name and Alias -> Value works.  If you put it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: You might need to skip example.com in the hostname field and add a trailing dot in the Alias field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Hostname* is the name `gibberish1._domainkey.example.com` and *Aliases to:* is the value `gibberish2.dkim.amazonses.com`